# ZwQueryDirectoryFile resumption 

Tags: c, windows, winapi, filesystems

If i have to scan a folder contains large number of entities, then I will call ZwQueryDirectoryFile api(i need it from Nt level)... file phase by phase allocating the buffer of size 4096.
This is a commmon usage. Except the first time, Everytime I have to keep the restartscan parameter as NULL, to get my job done.
I need to know the internals of it. How does the second ZwQueryDirectoryFile call resumes the fetching from the right place. how th eindex is supplied or stored to do the resumption correctly.

Comment: RestartScan is a boolean. True on the first call, false on continuation calls. There is no index parameter. Have you found the documentation yet?

Comment: @ David Heffernan,yes you are correct ,there is no index parameter,but how it hold the last data offset to continue in next call ...that was my question..

Comment: The HANDLE you get from zwopen is what manages the resumption; its an abstracted pointer to an internal structure that enables subsequent calls to fetch the next file. You don't have to worry about its implementation, windows will take care of it, you just need to keep on passing it in.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When the ZwQueryDirectoryFile routine is called for a particular handle, the RestartScan parameter is treated as if it were set to TRUE, regardless of its value. On subsequent ZwQueryDirectoryFile calls, the value of the RestartScan parameter is honored.

You can infer from this that the state of the enumeration is associated with the file handle in some manner.